# Scroll Two DIVs, One Shown but the other Hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rq2tvccg/14/

I have 2 DIVs which contain elements. Only one of the DIVs is shown at any time (the Toggle button switches their visibility). I need to simultaneously add an element which shows up in both Lists. The Element's ID is `List1_<Random>` or `List2_<Random>`.

The issue is that I need to scroll both DIVs to the just-added respective element. But this doesn't work because the Hidden DIV (whichever one) won't handle one of these expressions properly:

```
// Scroll to NEW for List 1
var elemAdded1 = $('#List1_' + id);
var pos1 = $(elemAdded1).position().top;
$("#list1").animate({scrollTop: pos1},1000); 

// Scroll to NEW for List 2
var elemAdded2 = $('#List2_' + id);
var pos2 = $(elemAdded2).position().top;
$("#list2").animate({scrollTop: pos2},1000);
```

Is there a solution to scroll both DIVs, such that when you switch to the other one, you're at the expected position?

**Note** The elements can be of arbitrary height, they don't have to be the same in List1 vs. List2, so we can't rely on the visible element height.

Comment: execute the code at the very moment the div becomes visible. You cant change scroll position of an element when it's not in view

Comment: As alternative, hide your inactive list by something other than 'display: none': apply 'position: absolute' and just juggle 'z-index' to put the target list forward. In this case you can scroll both containers.

Comment: You can also try `opacity` style to make this effect.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try your code by using `opacity` style.

Try this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rq2tvccg/22/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `scrollTop` value of both the lists container to bottom(or to the last child of list) on `add` button click.

For list1

```
$("#list1").animate({scrollTop: $('#list1 li:last-child').position().top},0);
```

For list 2

```
$("#list2").animate({scrollTop: $('#list2 li:last-child').position().top},0);
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tkqodtn9/)**

Answer (score 0):

I suggested adding a container div to find a total height of items added and use that to set scroll offsets. I am using `z-index` to toggle between two divs too. Try this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rq2tvccg/23/)

**Adding container**

```
<div class="list" id="list1">
  <div>    <!-- Container to find height -->
    <li>Item 1.1</li> ...
  </div>
</div>
```

**Use container's height to scroll**

```
$("#list1").animate({
    scrollTop: $('#list1 div').outerHeight()
}, 1000);
```

**Toggle between two divs using z-index**

```
.hidden {
    z-index: -1;
}

if ($('#list1').hasClass("hidden")) {
    $('#list1').removeClass("hidden")
    $('#list2').addClass("hidden")
}
```

Hope this help. :)